# Poor quality of texture painting

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting, color

Im still learning blender and have just created a simple racetrack with some red and white curbs. I have added colors by selecting the objects and applying different materials.

Now I want to add a little bit more details to the racetrack, like for example tire marks. As far as I understand, the best way to add more details to the colors would be to use texture painting. (Or is there any other good method to do this?)

So I unwrapped my racetrack with the "Smart UV Project" option and painted it by selecting the faces of my mesh and using the fill tool. However, the result does not look very clean but rather a bit pixelated, like you can see on the attached picture.

What can I do to make the texture look better with a cleaner edge? (The resolution I used for the texture painting was 4096x4096)

Thank you! :)

[image: Example]

Comment: Probably low texel density. Basically the UV Island is not covering too many pixels. No matter how much hi-res your image is, if the UVs don't use that much resolution, then you will have this pixellated look. Solution; try ur best to make sure that your UVs are able to efficiently cover as much of the image as possible. This comes with a bit of practice.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tipp. Is there the possibility to draw the edge a little softer, I think then you should also recognize the pixels a bit less?

Comment: The selection masking doesn't have any falloff AFAIK, you could just hand-paint the edges with no masking to not have them jagged.